# How to connect to a Microsoft Exchange server using Anypoint Studio?

Tags: networking, esb, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, microsoft-exchange

I am trying to create a flow that can access the Inbox of a given Microsoft Exchange account by using Anypoint Studio.

Microsoft Exchange uses MAPI protocol and Anypoint Studio has POP3 and IMAP endpoints available but does not have a MAPI endpoint.

Is there any alternative way to connect it? How do I proceed with this?

Comment: If we have to create a new user defined endpoint for this, can someone please tell me how to proceed with that as well

Answer (score 0):

The email connector can use pop3 or IMAP to talk to Microsoft Exchange. It is not compatible with the MAPI proprietary protocol. Note that usually the standard protocols are enabled.

Creating a custom connector is different for Mule 3 or Mule 4. It is certainly not something that can be explained in here. Check devkit or Mule Java SDK, documentation depending on your version.